# wrong use of #MV

Tags: files, directory, command-line

I've a done wrong use of `sudo mv` command. Example:

```
sudo Mv/home/USER/Downloads/piff.pdf /root/PDFs
```

Then the directory `/root/PDFs` has been changed to a plain text file.

I can undo the command?
I can retrieve the directory?

Comment: The command you typed is invalid so the answer you get from me has assuptions. Please clarify what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that you forgot to add a `/` at the end then ...

`sudo mv /root/PDFs /home/USER/Downloads/piff.pdf`

will restore the file to its original location and then you can redo the move with...

`sudo mv /home/USER/Downloads/piff.pdf /root/PDFs/`.

Warning: this ONLY works on the assumption that you intended to move the file to directory `/root/PDFs` and forgot to add the `/`. I do also want to make a comment that if that is the case  the actual `mv` you tried should have given an error (since the wrong move you made only works when the directory does not exist).